# External monitor drivers

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I got myself a Phillips monitor which most likely lacks drivers and therefore everything is very huge on it.

[image: Display Config]

As you can see the preview shows that my external monitor is the same size as an initial one, which is not true, everything on my monitor is kinda "stretched-out".

I had the same problem on Windows with the same monitor and I solved it after installing drivers from [here](http://www.p4c.philips.com/cgi-bin/cpindex.pl?ctn=237E7QDSB/69&hlt=Link_Software&mid=Link_Software&scy=HK&slg=AEN)

Sadly they only offer drivers for Windows, so I cannot use the same ones for my ubuntu machine.

Can someone offer me a solution on how to get a proper display?

Comment: The link you provided shows that the monitor is a 1080p display, and Ubuntu is showing that you have it set to 1920x1080, so I don't see where the problem is....

Comment: @AndroidDev Yep in the display config it shows everything correct, but when I connect monitor to Windows machine, it looks much better and more detailed than it does on ubuntu and as I mentioned, installing Phillips drivers solved the same issue on Windows.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the monitor so we can see the "streched-out" effect you're talking about?

Comment: @AndroidDev sure. As you can see the monitor is way bigger than my laptop screen and basically they display the same amount of content. There is no actual difference between my monitor and laptop screen in size. Everything is zoomed in. [here it is](http://i.imgur.com/ZAXtLKU.jpg) Took it with mobile just to see the difference.

Comment: I wouldn't say its "stretched out" if I haven't had an opportunity to try it out on Windows, where it looked much more appealing.

Comment: You need to provide exact details about the differences in configuration in Windows versus Ubuntu and show exactly what you're complaining about, for anyone to tell you what exactly is the difference. Your question is too vague. If you provide further details, I can update my answer to reflect. However, there are no monitor drivers in Linux. Windows doesn't really either, but it configures displays based on data from a database, which creates the necessity of some manufacturers to provide such "driver" installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitors do not have "drivers" really.

I'm also not sure what you're expecting. The external monitor is physically larger than the laptop's internal display, but they both have the same number of available pixels, so any content displayed on the external monitor will indeed be physically larger due to the lower DPI (the pixels themselves are larger, so there are fewer per inch).

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but how come that once I installed drivers from the Phillips websites, all my icons on windows machine shrinked twice in size and it was much more appealing?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Perhaps on Windows it was not correctly configured to start with, and was only displaying at 720p instead of 1080p? You have not provided any information about what the exact details behind that statement are.

Comment: @Viktor It's possible that the Philips "driver" display decreased the UI scaling by 50% or something. But, since both displays have the same resolution, it is perfectly normal (and expected) that they display the same amount of content. It isn't the physical size of the display that determines how much content shows on it, but rather the resolution.

Comment: The question wasn't about amount of content, but "sharpness" which is determined by pixel density (pixels per inch).